how to use list in the oracle sql table as a filter in python
i have almost 8000 barcodes in the excel and want use it in a oracle sql table as a filter. But since sql code has a limitation (only 1000 barcode) i tried to divide 8000 barcodes into chunks in a list.
But in the pandas query it is giving error.
I tried below query and got error. Can you help me or do we have another solution instead of using list?
        ': ORA-00904: "SRC": invalid identifier


Read the python oracledb documentation: Binding Multiple Values to a SQL WHERE IN Clause for the current recommendations.

For future reference, in Oracle DB 23ai the placeholder limit was increased from 1000 to around 65K.
